# "As for me" in the beginning of the sentence

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, sentence, speech

Could I use "As for me" in the beginning of the sentence?

For example, when somebody asks the whole group of people what was done, and one in that group answers what he did: "As for me, I did that and that...".

Comment: Yes, you can do that, it's perfectly good idiomatic English. If you're writing a newspaper or journal article, style guides recommend avoiding the first person.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is quite common to use "as for me" in English. However, using it at the beginning of a sentence would only make sense if it is a follow-up, alternative, or response to something someone else has said (usually, to mark contrast with another person's opinion).

```
"He prefers hiking and surfing. As for me, I would rather just stay at home and relax"
```

Comment: Is "as to me" 1) correct and 2) interchangeable?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov I would say it is incorrect. Have you encountered any specific example which uses "as to me" ?

Comment: No. Probably I heard it from somebody and it stuck in my mind. I was always confused when trying to choose the correct one.